# Find the kth node in Nth level of binary tree

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [K-th element in a heap tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13846585/k-th-element-in-a-heap-tree)

Given a binary tree, if parent is 0, then left child is 0 and right child is 1. if parent is 1, then left child is 1 and right child is 0. Root of the tree is 0. Find the kth node value which is present at Nth level

I tried to solve in this way. Suppose first level has `0`, second level has `01`, third level has  `01 - 10` (i.e complement of first half).
Similarly `0110 1001` on the fourth level.

Now how can I generalize this solution or any other way to solve this question?

Answer (score 3):

To generalize your idea, you could write a recursive procedure that gives the list of the elements of the n<sup>th</sup> level of the tree, since (like you said) every level can be obtained concatenating the upper level and its complement:

```
getLevel(level)

  if level == 0
    return [0]

  upperLevel = getLevel(level - 1)

  return upperLevel + complement(upperLevel)
```

Where `[...]` is a list, `+` is the concatenation of lists and `complement` changes `0` into `1` and viceversa.

Having this, you just have to get the `k`<sup>th</sup> element of the list generated by `getLevel(n)`.

This is probably not the optimal solution, it's just built on your idea (and it's easy).

Answer (score 2):

I manually generated first several bits, and got 0110100110010110. Google reveals this is [Thue-Morse sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence). Sequence [A010060](http://oeis.org/A010060) in OEIS. Comments on OEIS page have this line:

a(n) = S2(n) mod 2, where S2(n) = sum of digits of n, n in base-2 notation.

Here `n` is what in your case is `k`, and `N` in your case does not matter. So, to determine a(n) calculate number of 1's in `n`, and take least significant bit of this sum.