# How to insert into a binary max heap implemented as a binary tree?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, language-agnostic, tree, binary-heap

In a binary max heap implemented as a binary tree (where each node stores a pointer to its parent, left child, and right child), if you have the pointer to the root of the heap, how would you implement an insert operation? What's supposed to happen is the node first gets inserted as the last element in the last row. For array based, you could append to the array, but for tree based implementation, how would you find the right spot?

Comment: What is the shape of this linked list?  If parents can't necessarily point to their children, then in what order are the nodes linked?

Comment: The linked list will look like this
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap
So each node, will have a pointer to its parent, left child, right child and the key value. Null if it is the root or doesn't have the children.

Comment: @omega- Oh, okay.  That's not a doubly-linked list representation of a binary heap; that's a tree representation.

Comment: yeah but isn't doubly the same thing, because you have pointers going both ways (parent to child, and child to parent)?

Comment: @omega- They have the same representation, but a doubly-linked list is a very different structure than a general tree structure.  A doubly-linked list is a special case of a tree where each node points to its children and to its parent, so it would be incorrect to describe the tree representation as a linked list.

Comment: But in my case, the nodes do have the pointer to its 2 children and parent, so wouldn't it make it a doubly linked list? ( i did mention this two comments ago and in the main post)

Comment: @omega- No.  A doubly-linked list specifically implies that you can start at the first node, then continuously iterate forward through all of the nodes.  The tree structure doesn't have this property - if you continuously follow just one link, you will not reach all nodes in the tree.

Answer (score 1):

In [this older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13846585/k-th-element-in-a-heap-tree), I gave a short algorithm that uses the binary representation of the number *k* in order to find a way to select the *k*-th node out of a binary heap in a top-down traversal.  Assuming that you keep track of the number of nodes in the explicit tree representation of the binary heap, you could do the following to do an insert operation:

1. Using the above algorithm, determine where the new node should go, then insert the node at that position.
2. Continuously bubble the node upward either by rewiring the tree to swap it with its parent or by exchanging the data fields of the node and its parent until the element is in its final position.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So if you do not know the size of the heap, then you cannot use this?

Comment: @omega- That's correct.  That said, it's quite each to track the size of the heap, and doing so is enormously beneficial to performance.  If you don't track the size of the heap, the complexity of an insertion will be O(n), since you might have to look at every node in the tree to determine where the insertion point is.  If you track the size, this drops to O(log n), which is a huge performance win.

Comment: What would be the algorithm to insert (assuming you don't know the size) that gives the O(n)?

Comment: @omega- You could do a BFS over the tree, ordering nodes from left to right.  The very last node you visit will be either (a) right next to the insertion point (if the last row isn't full), or (b) at the end of the row, because you need a new row.  Based on that, you can then find the right insertion point.  Or, you could just count the number of nodes in O(n) time and then use my original technique. :-)  In all seriousness, it's needlessly complicated to not store the node count - it's dramatically simpler than the alternative, and there is no reason not to.

Comment: The described algorithm adds a node at the "end" in log(n) + another O(log(n)) for bubbling. The insertion path and the bubble path are identical. Hence you can insert a node by one downwards traversal over this path (no need for parent pointers anymore). Algortihm: go to next node on path using the bit algorithm described; compare this path node with the insertion node; if it's bigger place the insertion node at the position of the path node and set insertion node = path node; continue with the (new) insertion node until you reached the end of the path and add the insertion node there. Done!

Answer (score 1):

If you hang you new vertex under any leaf of your tree (as left or right successor, doesn't matter), and then repair the heap from this new vertex to the top (that is, regarding every other vertex with successors, swap it with the greater successor and climb up if needed), your  new element will find it's rightful place without breaking the heap. However, this will only guarantee you that every other insert operation will take O(h) time, where h is the maximum height of the tree. 
It's better to represent heap as an array, obviously, because that way it's guaranteed that every insert operation will take O(logN) time.

Comment: thats true, but I am trying to do it as a tree implementation.

Comment: If you are trying to make the tree a complete binary tree (as is usually the case), then this setup will not work, since you won't know which leaf to insert at.

Comment: As I pointed out in this answer, it doesn't matter which leaf do you choose. As long as you will do backwards-repair after inserting every new vertex, your heap will be consistent. But it will not be optimal.

Comment: If you want it to be optimal, you can just insert the new element under the leaf, closest to the root. Then the insert operation will always take O(logN) time, because the tree will be self-adjusting.

Answer (score 0):

To find the exact location as to where the new node is supposed to be inserted, we use the binary representation of the Binary Heap's Size. This takes O(log N) and then we bubble it up which takes O(log N). So the insertion operation takes O(log N)... For a detailed explanation check out my blog's post on Binary Heaps -

http://theoryofprogramming.com/2015/02/01/binary-heaps-and-heapsort-algorithm/

I hope it helped you, if it did, let me know...! ☺