# Placing a new node into the next available position in a binary tree heap?

Tags: c, algorithm, heap

Let's say I have this data structure for a minimum heap:

```
struct node{
    int height;
    struct node *parent;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
};
```

What I want to do is add a new node into the next available position (keeping the min heap property does not matter at this point.) What I have so far is in the case of an empty tree (the root is instantiated earlier to NULL earlier in the code). I am having trouble figuring out the logic in the case that a root already exists. I need to add the elements in one by one. I understand how to do this using a heap as an array, but I need to do it using a heap as a binary tree.

```
void insert(int number)
{
    struct node *nodeToInsert;
    nodeToInsert=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    nodeToInsert->value = number;

    if(root == NULL)
    {
        root = nodeToInsert;
        root->left = NULL;
        root->right = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: if the root exists, traverse to a node till you don't find a null node

Comment: This is related to, but not exactly a duplicate of, this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13846585/k-th-element-in-a-heap-tree/

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to know how to descend a complete binary tree to insert the next node.  All you need for this is to know how many nodes are already in the bottom level.  The bits of this number tell you how to turn (left or right) as you move down the tree to the next available position.  Happliy, you can get the number of nodes in the bottom level from the total number of items in the tree, which you normally want to track anyway.

```
// Let n be the current number of nodes in the tree.
// Subtract sizes of levels until we're at the last.
for (ls = 1, n_levels = 0; ; ls *= 2, n_levels++) {
  if (n - ls < 0) break;
  n -= ls;
}
// n now contains number of nodes in bottom level
// n_levels contains the number of complete levels above.
struct node *p = root;
for (bit = 1 << (n_levels - 1); bit != 1; bit >>= 1)
  if (n & bit)
    p = p->right;
  else
    p = p->left;
if (n & 1)
  p->right = new_node();
else
  p->left = new_node();
```

For example say n = 10.  So we have a perfect tree of 7 nodes plus 3 on the lowest, incomplete level.  The first loop subtracts 1, 2, then 4, so finishes with n = 3 = 011_2 and n_levels = 3.  Consequently, the second loop creates the bit mask 1 << 2 = 4 = 100_2.  The loop therefore moves down the tree with `p = p->left` for the high order bit 0 of n, then `p = p->right` for the 1. The final bit is a 1, therefore it puts the new node at `p->right`.  This is the correct place (11) as you can see in this picture:

```
        === 1 ---
      //         \
      2           3
    /  \\       /   \
   4     5     6     7
  / \   / \\
 8   9 10  11
```

Note the pseudocode above does not handle the n=0 case, but your code already does that.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the statement of the problem.  Given the objective of a binary tree, with an arbitrary start value, (i.E. tree sorted on the value field) neither node first nor branch first traversal of the tree will lead to the shortest path to finding/deleting/inserting a node, given the above suggested code..

Comment: @user3629249  The problem is not clearly stated, but I gathered that he is trying to duplicate the standard min heap algorithm - which is normally implemented with an array - using a pointer structure instead.  What I described is how you'd do the initial insert before sifting up to the correct location.  I may have it wrong, too.

Answer (score 0):

Oof, it's not easy. You basically need to count the depth of each non-full node, and insert under the leftmost one with minimal depth.

It gets a lot easier if you know how many nodes are in the tree already. Once you have that, you can just traverse down to the `n+1` position and put the node there.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know the size beforehand. This is for an assignment. The program takes a text file input of commands (either insert or delete). The commands are followed by the value that should be inserted or deleted. I must display the tree after each insert and delete, which is why it must be done one by one.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could tackle this. One possible solution is using a queue.

Here is an example implementation in python:

```
def insert(self,node):
    if self.root is None:
        self.root = node
        return node
    else:
        q = Queue()
        x = self.root
        while x is not None:
            if x.left is None:
                x.left = node
                return node
            elif x.right is None:
                x.right = node
                return node
            else:
                q.add(x.left)
                q.add(x.right)
            x = q.remove()
```